# #!/bin/bash showing when there is no file. #!/bin/bash Expected binary operator

Tags: bash, shell

In our program, we let the shell wait for some specific files and if found execute the next bash. 
The code was working perfectly some days ago but recently it's showing some weird error.

First, let's see the code:

```
#!/bin/bash -xv
...
...

field 1 << END |
${interface_redpost_rcv}/__TEMP__/${redpost_id}/xyz.csv.*.IF //files that match this format
${interface_redpost_rcv}/__TEMP__/${redpost_id}/abc.csv.*.IF //and this
...
...

END
while read fn ; do
  while : ; do
    [ -e ${fn} ] && break

    sleep 10

    # リミット
    [ $(date +%H%M) -lt ${limit} ] || exit 1
  done
done
```

if there is any file that matches that format from the beginning, the loop breaks and it work perfectly but the problem starts when there is no file at the execution time.

It constantly loops through the whole day without ever skipping even if there are files now.

LOG:

```
+ field 1
+ read fn
+ :
+ '[' -e '#!/bin/bash' -xv ']'
/home/batch/bash/EXAMPLE.BASH: 50 line: [: Expected binary operator
+ sleep 10
++ date +%H%M
+ '[' 2120 -lt 2359 ']'
....
....
....
```

And in the log where is `'[' -e '#!/bin/bash' -xv ']'`, this `#!/bin/bash` coming from?

BASH version :

```
GNU bash, version 4.2.46 (2) -release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

It would be very helpful if someone could point out where the problem is and if there is any other better solution to implement wait for files on bash.

Comment: You didn't say how you were executing the program, but _always_ double-quote your variables unless you intentionally want another behaviour. `[ -e "${fn}" ]` is correct.

Comment: Paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Thank you sir for your fast reply. The files are given execute permission and executed with the path and file name. And also there is a Software called job automation that manages all the bash files and automates the whole process. Just left office. I will do first thing in the morning tomorrow is check with the site you have given me. Thanks for you kind suggestion.

Comment: The script is fine when executed from other directories. 
Is there anything regarding bash acting differently depending on its location?
Will be waiting for you precious advice.